# Automatically calculate Inno Setup component size based on size of included files

Tags: inno-setup

I've `Files` and `Components` like this:

```
[Files]
Source: Src\MyApp\*.*; DestDir: {app}; \
    Flags: overwritereadonly ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs;

[Components]
Name: "MyApp"; Description: "MyDescription; Types: full custom; Flags: fixed; \
    ExtraDiskSpaceRequired: 384827392;
```

In case of any change in `Src\MyApp` I've to manually adjust the `ExtraDiskSpaceRequired` value.

There are functions `FileSize` and `FileSize64` but I didn't figure out how to use it for `ExtraDiskSpaceRequired`.

How to define `ExtraDiskSpaceRequired` dynamically?

[image: ExtraDiskSpaceRequired]

Answer (score 0):

Solved with adding `Components: MyApp` to the `Src\MyApp\*.*` `Files` entry:

```
[Files]
Source: Src\MyApp\*.*; DestDir: {app}; \
    Flags: overwritereadonly ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs; \
    Components: MyApp;

[Components]
Name: "MyApp"; Description: "MyDescription; Types: full custom; Flags: fixed;
```

Many thanks to [Martin Prikryl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/850848/martin-prikryl)

Comment: Good. Though next time, please allow the one who proposed the solution to post it as an answer, instead of posting it on your own :)